# Can I put Adf.ly links in my answers?

Tags: support, spam

Can I use *Adf.ly* links in my answers **to "reward" my work**?

Comment: What do you mean by "reward your work?"  In general, link shorteners are discouraged; we'd rather see the actual link, thank you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's a site that pays you whenever people click links you've created.  This is funded by advertisements injected by the link shortener provider (or something along these lines, just looking at their homepage so far).

Comment: Yeah, no.  You can "reward your work" somewhere else.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ideally this site would be added to a blacklist, while we're on the topic.

Comment: @Servy - It has been, for a while.

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No. That would be spam/promotional content.

Link shorteners are bad enough as they are. Post the original link, or include the actual content from the site.

Answer (score 41):

adf.ly links are blacklisted on Stack Overflow, so you can't post them anywhere.

For the reasoning behind this, see ["What to do about clickbank, adfly and similar “referral” programs?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122659/what-to-do-about-clickbank-adfly-and-similar-referral-programs) and ["Correct procedure for dealing with adf.ly links (shortening service that pays poster)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105208/correct-procedure-for-dealing-with-adf-ly-links-shortening-service-that-pays-po).