# Why are Q votes based on the topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting

I found [Can I comment a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244777/3453226). Body is **38** characters. **+1477** votes.

I asked [Can I put Adf.ly links in my answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258216/3453226). Body is **57** characters. **-22** votes.

I also asked [How to store JSON data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23956154/3453226). **Lot of hours** used to improve my incorrect english. **0** votes. **1** small answer.

Why are question votes based on the topic? ***Why aren't these votes based on the "explanation level"?***

Comment: Meta voting is *different*; people responded to your Adf.ly question with downvotes because they feel that using such links goes against the spirit of the site. You cannot compare that to a *5 year old question* on Stack Overflow, that's comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: The JSON question is popular because over the past 5 years, loads of people had the same question and felt that that question was helpful to them. Your JSON question applies to a far more limited audience and has *not* had 5 years to accumulate votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you mention three totally different questions:

- **[Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244777/3453226)**: This was asked in 2008. Rules have changed on quality. Plus, it has had many years of people finding it through search and possibly voting on it.
- **[Can I put Adf.ly links in my answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258216/can-i-put-adf-ly-links-in-my-answers)**: Meta works differently. The downvotes here are used to say "I don't agree."
- **[Store JSON data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956154/how-to-store-json-data-in-java)**: I, personally would not say that this is a question worthy of an uproar of upvotes:

  1. You ask many questions instead of just one.
  2. "*What is the best? Do you know others?*" - That means it is primarily opinion based and asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense based on your examples.

Your Meta question was heavily down voted because people disagree with your idea, it has nothing to do with how many characters you typed.

People vote on questions as they see fit. Unfortunately a question doesn't get up votes on Stack Overflow just because it is well laid out or well asked - it has to grab people's attention and make them think *"Yeah! That's a great question..."*.

Not getting an up vote for your question is no big deal - at least it didn't get down voted. The system is deliberately skewed to prevent people accumulating large amounts of rep by asking questions (not that you've attempted to do that). Getting up votes on your question is also no guarantee of getting any more (or better quality) answers.