# Why would a moderator keep spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745718/file-upload-with-circle-progress-bar) there is a link to `adf.ly` network.

> [image]

Authors of such links get paid for visits, and it's safe to assume the question was deliberately made to force users into visiting it. I've tried flagging it as spam, and the flag was declined. When I added this description, it got declined once more.

I'm not going to question the resolution of moderator, but I certainly miss the point. What could be a reason moderator have kept the spam?

Comment: What's wrong with editing to link directly to the destination and just removing the link shortener? Why does it need to be *deleted* as spam?

Comment: For me (on iPad) it has a 5 second countdown then doesn't go anywhere and when I click the "skip ads" button it takes me through a succession of dubious redirects.

Comment: @animuson First, it's not a link shortener. It's an ad network in first place, which is usually used for shady deeds like selling marijuana or illegal casinos. Link shorteners don't show ads. Second, it doesn't even go to the destination for me, constantly showing more and more ads.

Comment: I don't know what's happening for all of you, but I had no problem getting through to the fiddle after the countdown...

Comment: I guess the question was "How do I create a web site that's just as annoying as this one?"  Hard to tell.

Comment: I'm guessing the mod who handled it had the same experience as animuson where nothing went wrong when following the link. Describing to the moderator what happened to Martin and/or pointing out you never reach the destination may have been more effective. "Bad things happen to the user clicking the link" is more worrisome than "Something good happens for the OP".

Comment: [`adf.ly` links are blacklisted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258216). Request: can we blacklist `atomcurve.com` too?

Comment: Actually using the ad.fly link I can't get to the content, it just redirects me to the ad website. (maybe because of my adblock)

Comment: cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105208/correct-procedure-for-dealing-with-adf-ly-links-shortening-service-that-pays-po

Comment: @PaulCrovella Sure but if the mod never actually sees an ad when they click on the link then the flag looks like a mistake.

Comment: Sometimes you want an answer. Sometimes you want money. Sometimes....well...you want both...

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I thought selling marijuana wasn't "shady" anymore.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I had missed that it was an adf.ly network link, it looked like every other *I have a problem with my site here, fix my CSS or recommend me a JS lib* question that occasionally gets mis-flagged as spam.

And that was *still the case here*, there is a genuine question with a genuine attempt to supply code. It was *hugely* misguided of the OP to try and put that behind a monetised redirect, but it was still an attempt at asking a question. I use an adblocker so the fact that atomcurve.com is yet another ad monetised redirector had evaded me.

As such I would probably have done what Animuson did: move the linked content into the question, and disputed the spam flag rather than dismiss it.

I've asked Shog9 to add `atomcurve.com` to the link shortener blacklist (now completed). All link shorteners (except for a few highly specialised ones like the one for YouTube or Amazon) are disallowed, but adf.ly redirectors should have a special circle in hell reserved for them in my opinion.

Comment: `adf.ly redirectors should have a special circle in hell reserved for them in my opinion.` +1

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih I don't mind AdFly links as long as the site that uses them is upfront with you about the fact that they use them. I've seen a few sites that will say something like "before you are taken to your destination, you will be redirect to AdFly."

Comment: @DavidB "Before we annoy you with ads you don't want to see, we're going to waste even more of your time telling you about it". Here's to the day when all advertisers are dead and buried.

Comment: Yeah I know my statement sounds ridiculous but I can understand why some sites use it. For some websites, that's all they have in terms of income.

Comment: "there is a genuine question with a genuine attempt to supply code" Nope, the "code" in that "question" is a copypasta from the [examples on the jquery-asPieProgress GitHub](https://github.com/amazingSurge/jquery-asPieProgress/blob/master/examples/index.html). As such, "It was hugely misguided of the OP to try and put that behind a monetised redirect" is also wrong - that's the *only* reason that "question" was posted. @polkovnikov.ph was 100% correct in flagging this crap as spam, and declining that flag is 100% wrong.

Comment: @IanKemp: then use a custom flag if you find such content, the moment it deviates from the usual 'cheap viagra here, come get some at this url' patterns.

Comment: @DavidB I _do_ mind AdFly links, and if I ever click on one by mistake, it never goes anywhere; I only end up on a blank screen. (My adblocker does that.)

Comment: @IanKemp Stop assuming bad intentions here. It's far more likely that they used that service because we block users from just posting links to jsfiddle.net with no code, and they didn't feel like doing that. Spammers don't come back and continue participating on the question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's strange. AdFly used to have AdBlock detection built in and it would display an alert to disable it if one was detected.

Comment: @animuson I strongly suggest adding "stop assuming bad intentions" somewhere to guide reviewers. It's easy to fall under the influence of "watchman syndrome" and blame people for bad intentions when they're just being stupid.

Comment: @DavidB: I have a tricked-out version that evades that detection. They add ads, we block, they detect the blocker, we block the block detector, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait until they start detecting the block on the AdBlock detector.

Comment: The end result of the counter detection/blocking rule for me is generally a dead site.  I write a lot of my own blocker rules to decrappify (a much broader category than just blocking ads) sites. For those that try to play the "we you're blocking us, please whitelist our third party future malware distribution servers through" game (or otherwise degrade awfully as I start swinging the fire ax) my rule is never to remove rules or try troubleshooting sites if they fail more completely after an update.  if that means they end up unusable (Wired most of the last year, Vice more recently), oh well.

Comment: @DavidB: https://github.com/hletrd/FuckFuckFuckAdBlock

Comment: If you really want to keep the site from detecting AdBlock, you may have to resort to using a GreaseMonkey script or something to bypass that detection. Of course I once found a site that wouldn't let me in because I was using GreaseMonkey... Had to write another GreaseMonkey script to get around _that_.

Comment: @DanNeely I usually just use the Chrome dev tools to set the display of the alert to be invisible.

Comment: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2017/06/23/currency/